# Ubuntu server boot issue, initramfs prompt

Tags: boot, initramfs

Completely new to ubuntu and Open VPN. A Client of mine has had this same setup for years and found this morning the server is booted and sitting at a prompt for (initramfs).

After rebooting the server it gives several errors:

- mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /root failed: no such device
- Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
- mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: no such file or directory
- Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init

Is the server dead and/or do I have to rebuild from scratch? Any help would be appreciated!

[image: fdisk -l]

[image: fsck -f /dev/sda1]

Comment: See my initial answer. We have to start somewhere... Also, do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: I believe I do, yes. Should I boot to that first?